# Receiving Thread 1 error related to IF statement

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I understand this is a common error but I can't figure out why I am receiving it: `Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`:

[image]

Is there something specifically wrong with my code? To give some context the code is trying to determine if a particular item is on special and if it is then it strikes out the item's previous price that is displayed in the view controller.

Comment: What's the count of `globalVariable.specialBool`?

Comment: in while condition change <= to <

Comment: If globalVariable.specialBool is array, than why are sure that count of previousPrice array is the same with specialBool. Do you have indexOfBound error in the terminal?

Comment: And the count of `globalVariable.previous`? You must be sure these two arrays have the same count. And array index is zero based, so you probably need to change `while i <= xxxxx` to `while i < xxxx`

Comment: @Fujia This resolved the error. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I will make my comment an answer, and please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `globalVariable.previous` and `globalVariable.specialBool` have the same count. Otherwise, the access to `globalVariable.specialBool` will crash.

Additionally, `while i <= xxxx` probably needs to be changed to `while i < xxxx` because array index is zero based.